# How to insert current date to a curl command?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm trying to insert today's date to my curl command but I can't get the date command to display the correct date.

```
root@elk01:~# curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/"$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d)"/_search?pretty'
{
    "error":
        {"root_cause":        
            [
                {"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason" : "invalid version format: -U +%Y.%M.%D)\"/_SEARCH?PRETTY HTTP/1.1"}
            ],
                "type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid version format: -U +%Y.%M.%D)\"/_SEARCH?PRETTY HTTP/1.1"
        },
    "status":400
}
```

I've tried:

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/"$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d)"/_search?pretty'
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/\"$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d)\"/_search?prett
y'
curl -s -XGET "http://localhost:9200/\$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d)/_search?prett
y"
```

But none of them actually use the result of `date -u +%Y.%m.%d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following command did the job for me:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/`date -u +%Y.%m.%d`/_search" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}'
```